# vlans for corp and guest networks SSID broadcast

Tags: switch, vlan, access-point, guest

Cenario:
Two separated physical connections:
01 Corp (Internet, shared network resources, etc)
192.168.10.x
02 Guest
192.168.1.x (Internet only)

AP: ZyXEL NWA3560-N
Lab switch: HP 1810-24G

What I’m trying to accomplish is connecting two different networks in the same switch and setting the Access Point to broadcast two different SSID.

I guess I need to create two different vlans.

Let’s say:
Vlan10 for Corp and vlan20 for Guest

Corp uplink on switch port 1
Guest uplink on switch port 2
AP on switch port 3

What about tagged and untagged configurations? 
Port 1 tagged for vlan10
Port 2 tagged for vlan20
Port 3 tagged for vlan10 and vlan20? How far am I to set things up?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- create two SSIDs on WAP and associate them with the two transport VLANs
- set WAP uplink (to switch) to transport both VLANs, one untagged, all others tagged (trunk port)
- create the two VLANs on the switch
- set switch downlink port (to WAP) to transport both VLANs, identical to port config in WAP
- connect VLANs to your router with a VLAN trunk port identical to your WAP link (alternatively, use a dedicated port for each VLAN untagged)